# Custom Error Page not working when getErrorPath() returns path other than "/error"

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Spring boot: 2.2.2
IDE: Spring Tool Suite

One of the ways to create a custom error page is to create a controller class that implements `ErrorController`. By overriding the `getErrorPath()` method and returning `/error`, I am able to return the expected custom error page.

But when I return another path, other than `/error`, I get the following error:

> This localhost page can’t be found. No webpage was found for the web address: http://localhost:8080/bruce

Why is that so?

```java
@Controller
public class MyErrorController implements ErrorController{

 // @RequestMapping("/error")
    @RequestMapping("/error1")
    public String handleError() {
        return "customError";
    }

    @Override
    public String getErrorPath() {

        //return "/error"; 
        return "/error1"; 
    }
}
```

Comment: is the file `customError.html` available under `resources/templates`?

Comment: Yes, there is. That is why when i change the return value of getErrorPath() to "/error", and the Request Mapping annotation to @Requestmapping("/error"), the customError.html under resources/templates is displayed as expected.  Strange , right?

Answer (score 2):

So, it turns out that the output of the `getErrorPath` is not used to redirect to the `RequestMapping` of `handleError`.

If you provide the following `ErrorController`, on error it will still redirect to `/error` when an error occurs:

```java
@Controller
public class MyErrorController implements ErrorController {

    @RequestMapping("/error")
    public String handleError() {
        return "customError";
    }

    @Override
    public String getErrorPath() {
        return "/some-non-existing-path";
    }
}
```

I even found out that the following code works, and the `RuntimeException` is never triggered:

```java
@Controller
public class CustomErrorController implements ErrorController {

    @RequestMapping("/error")
    public String handleError() {
        return "customError";
    }

    @Override
    public String getErrorPath() {
        throw new RuntimeException("This will not be called.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Interestingly, you are right!  So does that mean there is bug in the spring boot framework? Or is there something i missing down here?

Comment: It is possible that this is a bug, *or* we are indeed missing something :) It could be that this `getErrorPath` is used by other Spring constructs to get an error page without having to inspect the `@RequestMapping` of an `ErrorController`.

Comment: Ok! Thanks. I will raise this bug to the pivotal forum, hopefully they can provide a clear answer for this.

Comment: That's a good idea! Could you post the link to the bug issue in this thread? And could you accept my answer?

Comment: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/19844

Once pivotal  acknowledged this issue as a bug, I will accept your reply as answer, Otherwise reader who read this post now would really think it is a bug in the framework, when this is not confirmed yet.

Comment: It has been a bug for a long time, at least 3-4 years now.